# On "for all" in if and only if statements in probability theory and stochastic calculus

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, expectation, martingales

1 In my friend's Probability Theory long test there was this question:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$ be a probability space on which is
>   defined all sub-$\sigma$-algebras, events and random variables in this
>   problem.
>
> Define the independence of any two sub-$\sigma$-algebras
>   $\mathfrak{F}_1$, $\mathfrak{F}_2$ of $\mathfrak{F}$.

My friend's answer was:

> Let $F_1 \in \mathfrak{F}_1$ and $F_2 \in \mathfrak{F}_2$
>
> Definition:
>
> $\mathfrak{F}_1$ and $\mathfrak{F}_2$ are independent iff $P(F_1 \cap
>  F_2) = P(F_1)P(F_2)$.

Apparently he was deducted a point, and there was the following comment:

> "The arbitrary choice of $F_1$ and $F_2$ is part of the 2nd clause."

**What exactly is the difference?** I have a feeling it has something to do with the logic in the beginning steps of the "if" parts of the proofs of the ff propositions:

2 Also in Probability Theory (my friend is a year ahead of me)

> Theorem: Let X and Y be random variables in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$. Then $\mathfrak{L}_X = \mathfrak{L}_Y$ iff $E(g(X)) = E(g(Y)) \forall$ Borel functions g such that the expectations are well-defined.

The proof for the "if" part involved choosing a particular function $g$ and then showing that $\mathfrak{L}_X = \mathfrak{L}_Y$. It seems to me that for that particular function $g$, $\mathfrak{L}_X = \mathfrak{L}_Y$, but it does not necessarily hold true for other functions?

3 In Stochastic Calculus:

> Lemma (Martingale Transform)
>   An adapted sequence of real integrable random variables $X_0, X_1, X_2, ...$ is a martingale iff $\forall$ bounded predictable sequences $c_1, c_2, ...$, $E(\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k \Delta x_k)$

The proof for the "if" part involved choosing a particular sequence $c_k$ and then showing that the sequence $X_k$ was a martingale. It seems to me that for that particular sequence $c_k$, $X_k$ is a martingale, but it does not necessarily hold true for other sequences?

**Could it be that my thinking for 2 and 3 is actually instead for the ff statements**:

> Theorem: $\forall$ Borel functions g such that the expectations are well-defined, let X and Y be random variables in $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$. Then $\mathfrak{L}_X = \mathfrak{L}_Y$ iff $E(g(X)) = E(g(Y))$.
>
> Lemma (Martingale Transform)
>   $\forall$ bounded predictable sequence $c_1, c_2, ...$, an adapted sequences of real integrable random variables $X_0, X_1, X_2, ...$ is a martingale iff $E(\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k \Delta x_k)$

?

**If so, why exactly?**

Comment: For 1) your friend's definition makes it sound like F1 and F2 are fixed prior to definition (and hence the two algebras are independent if you can find just two sets for which the statement holds, instead of for any pair of sets). So, it probably should read "$P(F_1 \cap F_2) = P(F_1)P(F_2)$ for any $F_1$, $F_2$...", right? There's not much to argue about with regards to "logic in the beginning steps..." because the definition is the definition.

Comment: @Tyler "For 1) your friend's definition makes it sound like F1 and F2 are fixed prior to definition" --> THANKS. Perhaps I was unclear. I probably should have said that 2 and 3 have something to do with 1. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend's answer in case 1. is wrong because, according to this "definition", the independence of $\mathfrak{F}_1$ and $\mathfrak{F}_2$ would *depend* on the choice of  $F_1 \in \mathfrak{F}_1$ and $F_2 \in \mathfrak{F}_2$. Thus, this "definition" corresponds to some sort of independence of $\mathfrak{F}_1$ and $\mathfrak{F}_2$ *related to* $(F_1,F_2)$ in $\mathfrak{F}_1\times\mathfrak{F}_2$, not to an intrinsic property of $\mathfrak{F}_1$ and $\mathfrak{F}_2$.

Imagine for concreteness that  $P(F_1 \cap
 F_2) = P(F_1)P(F_2)$ and that $P(G_1 \cap
 G_2) \ne P(G_1)P(G_2)$, for some carefully chosen $F_1$ and $G_1$ in $\mathfrak{F}_1$ and $F_2$ and $G_2$ in $\mathfrak{F}_2$. Then what? Using your friend's "definition" twice, $P(F_1 \cap
 F_2) = P(F_1)P(F_2)$ hence $\mathfrak{F}_1$ and $\mathfrak F_2$ are independent, and  $P(G_1 \cap
 G_2) \ne P(G_1)P(G_2)$ hence $\mathfrak{F}_1$ and $\mathfrak F_2$ are not independent?

By the way, since $\varnothing$ belongs to every sigma-algebra, choosing $F_1=\varnothing$ ensures that  $P(F_1 \cap
 F_2) = P(F_1)P(F_2)$. Thus, *every* sub-sigma-algebras $\mathfrak{F}_1$ and $\mathfrak{F}_2$ would be independent?

Cases 2. and 3. are examples of the same fallacy.

Comment: Thanks Did. I was wondering if 2 and 3 were indeed related to #1